# Is there a tool to see kernel space mapping of a Windows exe?

Tags: windows, ollydbg, windbg, winapi

In Microsoft Windows, a 32bits process `calc.exe` has `0x0`-`0x80000000` (2GB) reserved as its user-space and the rest is kernel-space (2GB). So, a process has `2+2 = 4GB` of virtual space. This ratio could be 3:1 also.

The 2GB user space has the PEB information,the heap,the stack, the executable and other dll's which the the exe uses like kernel32.dll, user32.dll, etc.

- **Doubt 1>** What does the 2GB kernel space encompasses in itself ?

  Is there a tool to see kernel-space mapping (for the user-space mapping  I used OllyDbg).
- **Doubt 2>** What happens when `ntoskrnl.exe` runs ? It doesn't use the native API (but exports implementation of these native APIs to user-space via `ntdll.dll`. So, that native application could use it before win32 kicks in). Therefore, there should be no dlls in the virtual space of `ntoskrnl.exe`.

  Is `ntoskrnl.exe` located in kernel-space ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Please only ask one question per post. This answer is in response to your first of two questions.*

> Is there a tool to see kernel-space mapping

Yes, you can use [LiveKd](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897415.aspx) to examine the contents of kernel space.

For example, I can see the loaded modules and their addresses in kernel-space with the command [`lmvk`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552026.aspx):

```
kd> lmvk
start    end        module name
80bd5000 80bdd000   kdcom      (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\kdcom.pdb\F48BD9BC030C43D89689518F892586901\kdcom.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: kdcom.dll
    Image path: kdcom.dll
    Image name: kdcom.dll
    Timestamp:        Mon Jul 13 20:08:58 2009 (4A5BDAAA)
    CheckSum:         000138B1
    ImageSize:        00008000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
82816000 82c28000   nt         (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\ntkrpamp.pdb\CE18EBF87B6A4C5CBF77806534BD94782\ntkrpamp.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: ntkrpamp.exe
    Image path: ntkrpamp.exe
    Image name: ntkrpamp.exe
    Timestamp:        Sat Nov 19 05:51:44 2011 (4EC79850)
    CheckSum:         003CAC28
    ImageSize:        00412000
    File version:     6.1.7601.17727
    Product version:  6.1.7601.17727
    File flags:       0 (Mask 3F)
    File OS:          40004 NT Win32
    File type:        1.0 App
    File date:        00000000.00000000
    Translations:     0409.04b0
    CompanyName:      Microsoft Corporation
    ProductName:      Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
    InternalName:     ntkrpamp.exe
    OriginalFilename: ntkrpamp.exe
    ProductVersion:   6.1.7601.17727
    FileVersion:      6.1.7601.17727 (win7sp1_gdr.111118-2330)
    FileDescription:  NT Kernel & System
    LegalCopyright:   © Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
82c28000 82c5f000   hal        (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\halmacpi.pdb\AE605D6C59454802AE1D485E0B089A571\halmacpi.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: halmacpi.dll
    Image path: halmacpi.dll
    Image name: halmacpi.dll
    Timestamp:        Sat Nov 20 02:37:38 2010 (4CE788D2)
    CheckSum:         00037FB1
    ImageSize:        00037000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
82e09000 82e14000   mcupdate_AuthenticAMD   (no symbols)           
    Loaded symbol image file: mcupdate_AuthenticAMD.dll
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\mcupdate_AuthenticAMD.dll
    Image name: mcupdate_AuthenticAMD.dll
    Timestamp:        Mon Jul 13 18:13:13 2009 (4A5BBF89)
    CheckSum:         0000BD79
    ImageSize:        0000B000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
82e14000 82e25000   PSHED      (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\pshed.pdb\5ACEAFD8AD3A46FEAD083AFDF675DA391\pshed.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: PSHED.dll
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\PSHED.dll
    Image name: PSHED.dll
    Timestamp:        Mon Jul 13 20:09:36 2009 (4A5BDAD0)
    CheckSum:         000108A2
    ImageSize:        00011000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
82e25000 82e2d000   BOOTVID    (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\bootvid.pdb\10C3ABD4165D4ED3A9493BB094B44AEA1\bootvid.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: BOOTVID.dll
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\BOOTVID.dll
    Image name: BOOTVID.dll
    Timestamp:        Mon Jul 13 20:04:34 2009 (4A5BD9A2)
    CheckSum:         00010FF0
    ImageSize:        00008000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
82e2d000 82e6f000   CLFS       (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\clfs.pdb\04F22EAC7BD04A1BA81A6FB5D319649F1\clfs.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: CLFS.SYS
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\CLFS.SYS
    Image name: CLFS.SYS
    Timestamp:        Mon Jul 13 18:11:10 2009 (4A5BBF0E)
    CheckSum:         000461C7
    ImageSize:        00042000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
82e6f000 82f1a000   CI         (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\ci.pdb\3358E6E48A5245F6AB97EA05356E020F1\ci.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: CI.dll
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\CI.dll
    Image name: CI.dll
    Timestamp:        Sat Nov 20 06:05:17 2010 (4CE7B97D)
    CheckSum:         000ADFF9
    ImageSize:        000AB000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
82f1a000 82f8b000   Wdf01000   (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\Wdf01000.pdb\A9E46808F4F748178D3071AA9EE76FB71\Wdf01000.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: Wdf01000.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\Wdf01000.sys
    Image name: Wdf01000.sys
    Timestamp:        Mon Jul 13 18:11:36 2009 (4A5BBF28)
    CheckSum:         000717B7
    ImageSize:        00071000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
82f8b000 82f99000   WDFLDR     (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\wdfldr.pdb\95D9DB57778548E6B6774520468479891\wdfldr.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: WDFLDR.SYS
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\WDFLDR.SYS
    Image name: WDFLDR.SYS
    Timestamp:        Mon Jul 13 18:11:25 2009 (4A5BBF1D)
    CheckSum:         00009DF6
    ImageSize:        0000E000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
82f99000 82fe1000   ACPI       (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\acpi.pdb\E7300A0CC3524834A4E1E55773C1901E1\acpi.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: ACPI.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\ACPI.sys
    Image name: ACPI.sys
    Timestamp:        Sat Nov 20 02:37:52 2010 (4CE788E0)
    CheckSum:         0004F583
    ImageSize:        00048000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
82fe1000 82fea000   WMILIB     (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\wmilib.pdb\F52B38A4800849D48BFFD48715A446A51\wmilib.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: WMILIB.SYS
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\WMILIB.SYS
    Image name: WMILIB.SYS
    Timestamp:        Mon Jul 13 18:11:22 2009 (4A5BBF1A)
    CheckSum:         0000B93D
    ImageSize:        00009000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
82fea000 82ff2000   msisadrv   (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\msisadrv.pdb\5D6926DA4AD1474BAE8CBDA5909F68201\msisadrv.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: msisadrv.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\msisadrv.sys
    Image name: msisadrv.sys
    Timestamp:        Mon Jul 13 18:11:09 2009 (4A5BBF0D)
    CheckSum:         0000CD81
    ImageSize:        00008000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
87800000 87811000   fileinfo   (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\fileinfo.pdb\EBD1E885413A4242AA515F1B06BB564F1\fileinfo.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: fileinfo.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\fileinfo.sys
    Image name: fileinfo.sys
    Timestamp:        Mon Jul 13 18:21:51 2009 (4A5BC18F)
    CheckSum:         0001E423
    ImageSize:        00011000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
8781a000 87844000   pci        (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\pci.pdb\2E2A912260694615A7E97AFBA3FA934E1\pci.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: pci.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\pci.sys
    Image name: pci.sys
    Timestamp:        Sat Nov 20 02:37:57 2010 (4CE788E5)
    CheckSum:         0002B72C
    ImageSize:        0002A000
    File version:     6.1.7601.17514
    Product version:  6.1.7601.17514
    File flags:       0 (Mask 3F)
    File OS:          40004 NT Win32
    File type:        2.0 Dll
    File date:        00000000.00000000
    Translations:     0409.04b0
    CompanyName:      Microsoft Corporation
    ProductName:      Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
    InternalName:     pci.sys
    OriginalFilename: pci.sys
    ProductVersion:   6.1.7601.17514
    FileVersion:      6.1.7601.17514 (win7sp1_rtm.101119-1850)
    FileDescription:  NT Plug and Play PCI Enumerator
    LegalCopyright:   © Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
87844000 8784f000   vdrvroot   (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\vdrvroot.pdb\3C9D6939EF564015B8D0728611C88C221\vdrvroot.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: vdrvroot.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\vdrvroot.sys
    Image name: vdrvroot.sys
    Timestamp:        Mon Jul 13 18:46:19 2009 (4A5BC74B)
    CheckSum:         00009326
    ImageSize:        0000B000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
8784f000 87860000   partmgr    (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\partmgr.pdb\7CA861FF7879483ABA38CE28186F293E2\partmgr.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: partmgr.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\partmgr.sys
    Image name: partmgr.sys
    Timestamp:        Sat Nov 20 02:38:14 2010 (4CE788F6)
    CheckSum:         0001BB55
    ImageSize:        00011000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
87860000 87868000   compbatt   (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\compbatt.pdb\EE14F03B54BF49B4B62A0EF912A59C8F1\compbatt.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: compbatt.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\compbatt.sys
    Image name: compbatt.sys
    Timestamp:        Mon Jul 13 18:19:18 2009 (4A5BC0F6)
    CheckSum:         00006941
    ImageSize:        00008000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
87868000 87873000   BATTC      (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\battc.pdb\53C47BEA2F08470BB58DFD1566285EC71\battc.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: BATTC.SYS
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\BATTC.SYS
    Image name: BATTC.SYS
    Timestamp:        Mon Jul 13 18:19:15 2009 (4A5BC0F3)
    CheckSum:         0000B849
    ImageSize:        0000B000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
87873000 87883000   volmgr     (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\volmgr.pdb\4AF04B598C494297B1C69F95823AA9F81\volmgr.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: volmgr.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\volmgr.sys
    Image name: volmgr.sys
    Timestamp:        Sat Nov 20 02:38:06 2010 (4CE788EE)
    CheckSum:         00016E1A
    ImageSize:        00010000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
87883000 878ce000   volmgrx    (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\volmgrx.pdb\433F00DD3CC34DE8BC3F9E4BDDACA5EE1\volmgrx.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: volmgrx.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\volmgrx.sys
    Image name: volmgrx.sys
    Timestamp:        Mon Jul 13 18:11:41 2009 (4A5BBF2D)
    CheckSum:         0004A22A
    ImageSize:        0004B000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
878ce000 878d5000   intelide   (no symbols)           
    Loaded symbol image file: intelide.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\intelide.sys
    Image name: intelide.sys
    Timestamp:        Mon Jul 13 18:11:19 2009 (4A5BBF17)
    CheckSum:         00006324
    ImageSize:        00007000
    File version:     6.1.7600.16385
    Product version:  6.1.7600.16385
    File flags:       0 (Mask 3F)
    File OS:          40004 NT Win32
    File type:        3.7 Driver
    File date:        00000000.00000000
    Translations:     0409.04b0
    CompanyName:      Microsoft Corporation
    ProductName:      Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
    InternalName:     intelide.sys
    OriginalFilename: intelide.sys
    ProductVersion:   6.1.7600.16385
    FileVersion:      6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)
    FileDescription:  Intel PCI IDE Driver
    LegalCopyright:   © Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
878d5000 878e3000   PCIIDEX    (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\pciidex.pdb\8B7BC6201128486CB5B03916EBD5FF8E1\pciidex.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: PCIIDEX.SYS
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\PCIIDEX.SYS
    Image name: PCIIDEX.SYS
    Timestamp:        Mon Jul 13 18:11:15 2009 (4A5BBF13)
    CheckSum:         0000FC04
    ImageSize:        0000E000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
878e3000 878f9000   mountmgr   (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\mountmgr.pdb\356DDF9839E040638E034EEA956C28F81\mountmgr.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: mountmgr.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\mountmgr.sys
    Image name: mountmgr.sys
    Timestamp:        Sat Nov 20 02:38:09 2010 (4CE788F1)
    CheckSum:         00014708
    ImageSize:        00016000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
878f9000 87922180   vmbus      (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\vmbus.pdb\35B5AB3E6BDF4D3FA0BDC6AC31AC97FC1\vmbus.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: vmbus.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\vmbus.sys
    Image name: vmbus.sys
    Timestamp:        Sat Nov 20 03:14:58 2010 (4CE79192)
    CheckSum:         0002F9E5
    ImageSize:        00029180
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
87923000 87935000   winhv      (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\winhv.pdb\5B6B8428A8FA4152919E805179599ED31\winhv.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: winhv.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\winhv.sys
    Image name: winhv.sys
    Timestamp:        Sat Nov 20 02:38:15 2010 (4CE788F7)
    CheckSum:         00010243
    ImageSize:        00012000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
87935000 8793e000   atapi      (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\atapi.pdb\EF544461A5D5482980C2CA01640A6D621\atapi.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: atapi.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\atapi.sys
    Image name: atapi.sys
    Timestamp:        Mon Jul 13 18:11:15 2009 (4A5BBF13)
    CheckSum:         00014C06
    ImageSize:        00009000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
8793e000 87961000   ataport    (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\ataport.pdb\C9AF9FE9166548FD86EFAC017F6023011\ataport.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: ataport.SYS
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\ataport.SYS
    Image name: ataport.SYS
    Timestamp:        Sat Nov 20 02:38:00 2010 (4CE788E8)
    CheckSum:         0002B87F
    ImageSize:        00023000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
87961000 87979000   lsi_sas    (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\lsi_sas.pdb\FCC2DAF36299423A9765B62D750A97461\lsi_sas.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: lsi_sas.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\lsi_sas.sys
    Image name: lsi_sas.sys
    Timestamp:        Mon May 18 19:19:55 2009 (4A11FB2B)
    CheckSum:         00024959
    ImageSize:        00018000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
87979000 879c1000   storport   (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\storport.pdb\1445D4DB7BA84A0081ABB729753A93942\storport.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: storport.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\storport.sys
    Image name: storport.sys
    Timestamp:        Thu Mar 10 21:56:00 2011 (4D799D50)
    CheckSum:         000277A3
    ImageSize:        00048000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
879c1000 879ca000   amdxata    (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\amdxata.pdb\5E66F230920844408A1EE389D50B6B4A1\amdxata.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: amdxata.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\amdxata.sys
    Image name: amdxata.sys
    Timestamp:        Fri Mar 19 11:19:01 2010 (4BA3A3F5)
    CheckSum:         000147B2
    ImageSize:        00009000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
879ca000 879fe000   fltmgr     (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\fltMgr.pdb\E6CA9E082E70438988788CB58DB340B01\fltMgr.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: fltmgr.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\fltmgr.sys
    Image name: fltmgr.sys
    Timestamp:        Mon Jul 13 18:11:13 2009 (4A5BBF11)
    CheckSum:         000382A8
    ImageSize:        00034000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
87a00000 87a0e000   pcw        (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\pcw.pdb\D368300F340A423EBBA32FBDDDEC24B91\pcw.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: pcw.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\pcw.sys
    Image name: pcw.sys
    Timestamp:        Mon Jul 13 18:11:10 2009 (4A5BBF0E)
    CheckSum:         000194CF
    ImageSize:        0000E000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
87a0e000 87a17000   Fs_Rec     (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\fs_rec.pdb\3465ED05A901452FAD07E77351F094591\fs_rec.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: Fs_Rec.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\Fs_Rec.sys
    Image name: Fs_Rec.sys
    Timestamp:        Mon Jul 13 18:11:14 2009 (4A5BBF12)
    CheckSum:         0000845A
    ImageSize:        00009000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
87a2a000 87b59000   Ntfs       (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\ntfs.pdb\6D39EA084D324936A61D6DBDE4D1172B2\ntfs.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: Ntfs.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\Ntfs.sys
    Image name: Ntfs.sys
    Timestamp:        Thu Mar 10 21:21:11 2011 (4D799527)
    CheckSum:         0012D977
    ImageSize:        0012F000
    File version:     6.1.7601.17577
    Product version:  6.1.7601.17577
    File flags:       0 (Mask 3F)
    File OS:          40004 NT Win32
    File type:        3.7 Driver
    File date:        00000000.00000000
    Translations:     0409.04b0
    CompanyName:      Microsoft Corporation
    ProductName:      Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
    InternalName:     ntfs.sys
    OriginalFilename: ntfs.sys
    ProductVersion:   6.1.7601.17577
    FileVersion:      6.1.7601.17577 (win7sp1_gdr.110310-1504)
    FileDescription:  NT File System Driver
    LegalCopyright:   © Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
87b59000 87b84000   msrpc      (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\msrpc.pdb\B4C428CFD1024C43BD3E2B10D1A8F0711\msrpc.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: msrpc.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\msrpc.sys
    Image name: msrpc.sys
    Timestamp:        Mon Jul 13 18:11:59 2009 (4A5BBF3F)
    CheckSum:         00036B4F
    ImageSize:        0002B000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
87b84000 87b97000   ksecdd     (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\ksecdd.pdb\A4060D19AD914446AB889720E6B7284C1\ksecdd.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: ksecdd.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\ksecdd.sys
    Image name: ksecdd.sys
    Timestamp:        Wed Nov 16 21:15:56 2011 (4EC47C6C)
    CheckSum:         00015ED3
    ImageSize:        00013000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
87b97000 87bf4000   cng        (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\cng.pdb\E729F2E7DC70413D986258B0E44C22CC1\cng.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: cng.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\cng.sys
    Image name: cng.sys
    Timestamp:        Wed Nov 16 21:36:35 2011 (4EC48143)
    CheckSum:         00068127
    ImageSize:        0005D000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
87c07000 87cbe000   ndis       (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\ndis.pdb\4DAAA54E2C26455DB2471D696BC8E6A62\ndis.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: ndis.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\ndis.sys
    Image name: ndis.sys
    Timestamp:        Sat Nov 20 02:39:19 2010 (4CE78937)
    CheckSum:         000BD48D
    ImageSize:        000B7000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
87cbe000 87cfc000   NETIO      (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\netio.pdb\7A33726ABE884384BFDFB951F05D13AC2\netio.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: NETIO.SYS
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\NETIO.SYS
    Image name: NETIO.SYS
    Timestamp:        Sat Nov 20 02:40:03 2010 (4CE78963)
    CheckSum:         0003F253
    ImageSize:        0003E000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
87cfc000 87d21000   ksecpkg    (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\ksecpkg.pdb\8C991B24F8F24A96B28B8268237920CF1\ksecpkg.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: ksecpkg.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\ksecpkg.sys
    Image name: ksecpkg.sys
    Timestamp:        Wed Nov 16 21:37:34 2011 (4EC4817E)
    CheckSum:         0002C883
    ImageSize:        00025000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
87d21000 87d60000   volsnap    (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\volsnap.pdb\1F66E7165E8F4BD982A34A9DFA1BBFD31\volsnap.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: volsnap.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\volsnap.sys
    Image name: volsnap.sys
    Timestamp:        Sat Nov 20 02:38:13 2010 (4CE788F5)
    CheckSum:         0003CA6D
    ImageSize:        0003F000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
87d60000 87d92000   fvevol     (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\fvevol.pdb\DC4549C710EE425F8956C7D82BFE83651\fvevol.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: fvevol.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\System32\DRIVERS\fvevol.sys
    Image name: fvevol.sys
    Timestamp:        Sat Nov 20 02:40:22 2010 (4CE78976)
    CheckSum:         000390DC
    ImageSize:        00032000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
87d92000 87db7000   CLASSPNP   (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\classpnp.pdb\64A86A6AD27D4730A78ECC25166E13562\classpnp.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: CLASSPNP.SYS
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\CLASSPNP.SYS
    Image name: CLASSPNP.SYS
    Timestamp:        Mon Jul 13 18:11:20 2009 (4A5BBF18)
    CheckSum:         0002BBFE
    ImageSize:        00025000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
87e00000 87e10000   mup        (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\mup.pdb\E96F69551E2447289250F71FB5AB6E0C2\mup.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: mup.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\mup.sys
    Image name: mup.sys
    Timestamp:        Mon Jul 13 18:14:14 2009 (4A5BBFC6)
    CheckSum:         00014283
    ImageSize:        00010000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
87e10000 87e18000   hwpolicy   (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\hwpolicy.pdb\0F041CEBADCA48F4BC65F68463272F1D1\hwpolicy.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: hwpolicy.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\hwpolicy.sys
    Image name: hwpolicy.sys
    Timestamp:        Sat Nov 20 02:37:35 2010 (4CE788CF)
    CheckSum:         0000B2B9
    ImageSize:        00008000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
87e18000 87e29000   disk       (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\disk.pdb\D2AD04F7F4BF45C8A8F0E2BF689326F11\disk.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: disk.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\disk.sys
    Image name: disk.sys
    Timestamp:        Mon Jul 13 18:11:28 2009 (4A5BBF20)
    CheckSum:         000152A4
    ImageSize:        00011000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
87e3e000 87f88000   tcpip      (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\tcpip.pdb\676C275B8EAE4B50A19255B333A152BA2\tcpip.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: tcpip.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\tcpip.sys
    Image name: tcpip.sys
    Timestamp:        Wed Sep 28 22:22:11 2011 (4E83E463)
    CheckSum:         0013EA1F
    ImageSize:        0014A000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
87f88000 87fb9000   fwpkclnt   (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\fwpkclnt.pdb\FDE8223F22C54AEA8061EE56EA16A0251\fwpkclnt.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: fwpkclnt.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\fwpkclnt.sys
    Image name: fwpkclnt.sys
    Timestamp:        Sat Nov 20 02:39:08 2010 (4CE7892C)
    CheckSum:         0003B983
    ImageSize:        00031000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
87fb9000 87fc1380   vmstorfl   (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\vmstorfl.pdb\D7FD176CC0134139B2EE4BEAF352AEE41\vmstorfl.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: vmstorfl.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\vmstorfl.sys
    Image name: vmstorfl.sys
    Timestamp:        Sat Nov 20 03:14:37 2010 (4CE7917D)
    CheckSum:         000131D0
    ImageSize:        00008380
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
87fc2000 87fca000   spldr      (no symbols)           
    Loaded symbol image file: spldr.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\spldr.sys
    Image name: spldr.sys
    Timestamp:        Mon May 11 11:13:47 2009 (4A084EBB)
    CheckSum:         0000767D
    ImageSize:        00008000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
87fca000 87ff7000   rdyboost   (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\rdyboost.pdb\53BB42ABE1404332962CA2AEA8301D331\rdyboost.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: rdyboost.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\rdyboost.sys
    Image name: rdyboost.sys
    Timestamp:        Sat Nov 20 03:00:07 2010 (4CE78E17)
    CheckSum:         000394EA
    ImageSize:        0002D000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
8ca08000 8ca49000   rdbss      (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\rdbss.pdb\A65B6296E0414A128A1951A1350D32C02\rdbss.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: rdbss.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\rdbss.sys
    Image name: rdbss.sys
    Timestamp:        Sat Nov 20 02:42:44 2010 (4CE78A04)
    CheckSum:         000464DE
    ImageSize:        00041000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
8ca49000 8ca53000   nsiproxy   (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\nsiproxy.pdb\C05F47CD56124B77BD71E3DFB669D4FF1\nsiproxy.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: nsiproxy.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\nsiproxy.sys
    Image name: nsiproxy.sys
    Timestamp:        Mon Jul 13 18:12:08 2009 (4A5BBF48)
    CheckSum:         0000939B
    ImageSize:        0000A000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
8ca53000 8ca5d000   mssmbios   (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\mssmbios.pdb\B9453B9B745D45DE974BA45D910B78481\mssmbios.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: mssmbios.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\mssmbios.sys
    Image name: mssmbios.sys
    Timestamp:        Mon Jul 13 18:19:25 2009 (4A5BC0FD)
    CheckSum:         0000B8F6
    ImageSize:        0000A000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
8ca5d000 8ca69000   discache   (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\discache.pdb\1F3066C30EA34CC381D3006454C11BD11\discache.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: discache.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\discache.sys
    Image name: discache.sys
    Timestamp:        Mon Jul 13 18:24:04 2009 (4A5BC214)
    CheckSum:         0000EDA3
    ImageSize:        0000C000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
8ca69000 8cacd000   csc        (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\csc.pdb\A6CAEC9D41C74DECA0E523C20AAB9A4F2\csc.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: csc.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\csc.sys
    Image name: csc.sys
    Timestamp:        Sat Nov 20 02:44:32 2010 (4CE78A70)
    CheckSum:         00065355
    ImageSize:        00064000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
8cacd000 8cae5000   dfsc       (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\dfsc.pdb\52BC36B80CED4847964EF156BC67E96E1\dfsc.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: dfsc.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\dfsc.sys
    Image name: dfsc.sys
    Timestamp:        Sat Nov 20 02:42:32 2010 (4CE789F8)
    CheckSum:         00015073
    ImageSize:        00018000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
...
```

Comment: Thankyou Jason I asked two questions because they were interlinked

Comment: Next time Ill keep it in mind to ssk a single question. ..

Answer (score 2):

if you have windbg installed open a command prompt and execute

C:>cdb -c "!address;.attach -k;g;!address;.detach;q" calc

```
    0:000> cdb: Reading initial command '!address;.attach -k;g;!address;.detach;q'

      BaseAddr EndAddr+1 RgnSize     Type       State                 Protect             Usage
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    *        0    10000    10000             MEM_FREE    PAGE_NOACCESS                      Free
    *    10000    12000     2000 MEM_PRIVATE MEM_COMMIT  PAGE_READWRITE                     <unclassified>
    *    12000    20000     e000             MEM_FREE    PAGE_NOACCESS                      Free
    *    20000    21000     1000 MEM_PRIVATE MEM_COMMIT  PAGE_READWRITE                     <unclassified>

    snip--------------------------------
PAGE_NOACCESS                      Free
    * 7ffb0000 7ffd4000    24000 MEM_MAPPED  MEM_COMMIT  PAGE_READONLY                      MemoryMappedFile "PageFile"
    * 7ffd4000 7ffdc000     8000             MEM_FREE    PAGE_NOACCESS                      Free
    * 7ffdc000 7ffdd000     1000 MEM_PRIVATE MEM_COMMIT  PAGE_READWRITE                     PEB [35c]
    * 7ffdd000 7ffdf000     2000             MEM_FREE    PAGE_NOACCESS                      Free
    * 7ffdf000 7ffe0000     1000 MEM_PRIVATE MEM_COMMIT  PAGE_READWRITE                     TEB [35c.d0; ~0]
    * 7ffe0000 7ffe1000     1000 MEM_PRIVATE MEM_COMMIT  PAGE_READONLY                      <unclassified>
    |-7ffe1000 7fff0000     f000 MEM_PRIVATE MEM_RESERVE PAGE_NOACCESS                      <unclassified>

    Attach will occur on next execution
    WARNING: Local kernel debugging requires booting with kernel
    debugging support (/debug or bcdedit -debug on) to work optimally.

      804d7000 - 001f9000
              Usage       KernelSpaceUsageImage
              ImageName   ntkrnlpa.exe

      81ec6000 - 00df0000
              Usage       KernelSpaceUsagePFNDatabase

      82cb6000 - 08000000
              Usage       KernelSpaceUsageNonPagedPool

      a71b7000 - 00004000
              Usage       KernelSpaceUsageKernelStack
              KernelStack 8ab4eda8 : 23c.6a8

snip-----------------------------------------------------------
      ba5a0000 - 00004000
              Usage       KernelSpaceUsageKernelStack
              KernelStack 8a717020 : 4.140

      ba5a4000 - 00004000
              Usage       KernelSpaceUsageKernelStack
              KernelStack 8aac0bd8 : 190.1b8

      bb800000 - 00400000
              Usage       KernelSpaceUsageSessionPool

      bbc00000 - 03400000
              Usage       KernelSpaceUsageSessionView

      bf000000 - 01000000
              Usage       KernelSpaceUsageSessionImage

      c1200000 - 1fe00000
              Usage       KernelSpaceUsageSystemCache

      e1000000 - 16800000
              Usage       KernelSpaceUsagePagedPool

      f7be0000 - 08000000
              Usage       KernelSpaceUsageNonPagedPoolExpansion

    Detached
    quit:

    C:\>
```

Comment: thank you blabb, it shows the memory map not the contents but nevertheless I will not have to use the vmap tool from now onwards.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Kernel mode memory is not process-specific. It is identical for all processes.

ntoskrnl.exe is not a process in itself. It is kernel image. Microsoft decided to use same file-format (PE) for the kernel image, as they use for other executables. Kernel image is shared by all processes.